# Insert attributed string NSAttributedString at current selection or cursor position in UITextField in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, nsattributedstring

I am using swift for iOS. I am trying to insert an NSAttributedString at the current cursor position or selection in a UITextField.

I use the function shouldChangeCharactersInRange on UITextFieldDelegate to manage different situations of inserting, deleting, copying and pasting text. That part works well.

If I use UIPasteboard with a standard string it calls shouldChangeCharactersInRange and works fine. I want to do the same with an attributed string.
Is there another way to do this by calling the paste selector directly on the UITextField? Any other ways?

I know that I can save the paste board items and restore them for a good user experience. That is not the crux of the matter.

Thanks

```
func insertWord(word: NSAttributedString) {
    // I really want to copy paste the attributed string
    UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().string = word.string
    myTextField.paste(self)
}
```

Comment: Please create [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Going through the Pasteboard to try and fake the system into doing this for you is not a winning solution.

A UITextField is a subclass of UITextInput.  You should be able to use that fact to get the selected range of text.  From there you should be able to get the attributed string from the text field and replace the range of the selection with the your new attributed text, and set the resulting attributed string back into the text field.

Comment: Yes, I ended up writing an extension of UITextField with my logic and it works fine. The trick was converting the text range to NSRange which I could find many examples of.